# Mysql: Find rows where column value ends with a specific substring

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column `url` where all the values are urls. I'm trying to update the value of a different column where-ever the aforementioned url ends with `.pdf`.

Can anyone help me with this? I haven't found an answer here on SO.

Comment: you can use the `right()` function

Comment: If you're also trying to handle extensions that are 4 letters or more, like `.jpeg`, you won't be able to use the `right()` method.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I might be oversimplifying... but based on your description, would [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) solve your problem?

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET DifferentColumn = 'NewValue'
WHERE Url LIKE '%.pdf'
```

Comment: I guess it would, the only thing is that the table is huge (several million records) and Like will probably take a while. I was hoping there was some kind of native string functions in Mysql, but it looks like I'm stuck with Like...

Comment: Well, it worked, and didn't even take that long, so thanks :-)

Answer (score 9):

You can use a LIKE condition with a leading wildcard. `%.pdf` means the column must end in `.pdf`

```
UPDATE mytable
SET newcolumn = 'PDF found'
WHERE yourcolumn LIKE '%.pdf'
```

Alternatively you could use the `right()` function

```
UPDATE mytable
SET newcolumn = 'PDF found'
WHERE right(yourcolumn,4) = '.pdf'
```

Answer (score 6):

In your WHERE clause, use something like `LOCATE('.pdf',url) > 0` to identify the record of interest.

As pointed out, this will give you any url that contains '.pdf' in the string...

If you definitely want the '.pdf' to be at the end, you can also try:

`LOWER(RIGHT(url,4)) = '.pdf'`

I would use LOWER or UPPER to deal with any case issues.

You can also use `LIKE %.pdf` (again, watch out for upper/lower case issues) as suggested
by others.

Comment: If `url` has a case-insensitive collation, you can forego the use of `LOWER`.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you are looking for the [like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) parameter.

for example:

```
SELECT column(s) FROM table WHERE URL LIKE '%.pdf'
```

Or you can update with

```
UPDATE table SET column = value, ..., WHERE URL LIKE '%.pdf'
```

The % is like saying anything before the .pdf is htis case.

Hope this helps.